# Event Registration as Organization

Tags: wordpress, civievent, profile

Most everything we do is based around an organization and not an individual. I've searched around and couldn't find an option for an event registration to be tied to the organization record and not the individual record.

Then I thought I could perhaps transfer the registration after someone registers to the organization but the options displayed are only to transfer to a person.

But I can manually enter a registration for an organization.

Is there a solution for this that others are using?

Comment: Welcome to SE, Since you are using wordpress it may be possible through Caldera form CiviCRM but not sure as its documentation says it supports only Contribution and membership. The CiviCRM form at the moment doesn't support on behalf Org registration or register organization through online.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saw someone comment on the latest Caldera update that it doesn't support events yet. Is there a way to transfer the registration to the organization once someone has registered?